# Take a picture with CvVideoCamera

Tags: ios, opencv, objective-c++

I'm trying to implement OpenCV in my iOS app.

CvVideoCamera is great because it has a delegate method that lets me process every frame of the camera preview, but I don't know how to extract one frame and save it as an image (aka taking a picture).

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks

Comment: I don't have experience in iOS app development but you can get some help from this link. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/ios/video_processing/video_processing.html#processing-frames

Comment: Can't you use `cv::imwrite` or whatever ios uses to save the image you are processing?

Comment: The thing is I don't want to save the image while processing (on the processImage method), I just want to save the image when pressing a UIButton.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. my solution is the best way either, but it still works. I am gonna do screen shot which I save to my photo album. Here is my code

```
-(IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageView.frame.size);

    [imageView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     UIImage *screenshot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    CGRect cropRect = CGRectMake(0 ,0 ,imageView.frame.size.width,imageView.frame.size.height);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([screenshot CGImage], cropRect);
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);

    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot , nil, nil, nil);

   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(screenshot , nil, nil, nil);
}
```

The only problem I have is the issue with the quality. How could I increase he quality?

Best regards,
Nazar

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy method to take a picture with CvVideoCamera. It is not an ideal method but it is quite easy. On another thread they suggest to override the opencv camera method. ([Capturing a still image from camera in OpenCV Mat format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182793/capturing-a-still-image-from-camera-in-opencv-mat-format))

In my method you just need to have an extra property named taken_image, and a method for take a photo.

```
@property cv::Mat taken_image;

- (void)processImage:(cv::Mat&)image {
    // Some processing over the image
    ...
    self.taken_image = image.clone();
}


- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {
    printf("Take Photo..\n");
    [camera stop];
    cv::Mat rgb_image;
    cv::Mat bgr_image = _taken_image.clone();
    // Change the color scheme for iOS
    cv::cvtColor(bgr_image, rgb_image, CV_RGB2BGR);
    // Here you have your image        
    UIImage *img = MatToUIImage(rgb_image);
    ...
    ...
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```